# How to do $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}$?

Tags: summation, residue-calculus

I'm a physicist with no clue how to calculate $S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}$.

One handbook says the answer is $\frac{1}{12}(3x^2 - 6 \pi x + 2 \pi^2)$ on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$, which would give the value everywhere since the sum is periodic in $2\pi$.

Altland's Condensed Matter Field Theory gives the value as

$\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi |x|}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4} + \dots$, giving no domain and with a weird absolute value, implying the series is valid everywhere and has higher powers. But how can this be correct? The series is periodic and those first three terms give the complete answer on $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$, so trying to define the result everywhere with an infinite power series seems senseless to me.

Anyway, can anybody shed light on how to perform the summation? I've tried writing $S$ as a contour integration, like so:

$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint dz g(z) \frac{\cos(i z x)}{-z^2} $, where $g(z) = \frac{\beta}{exp(\beta z) - 1}$, a counting function with simple poles at $z = i k$, $k = ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, \dots$, and the contour contains all the poles of $g(z)$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, ...$.

Now, this is not my expertise, but I want to learn. The trick now is to pick a different contour (possibly going off to infinity), such that the integral can be performed. I see that the product $g(z) \frac{\cos(i z x)}{-z^2}$ goes to zero at infinity, but I cannot see how to deform the contour such that the integral becomes tractable.

Comment: "trying to define the result everywhere with an infinite power series seems senseless to me" It does make sense. For instance, $\cos(x)$ itself is defined on the entire number line as
$$
\cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{720} + \cdots
$$As to whether the two solutions you have there coincide, and how the power series is supposed to continue, I do not know.

Comment: The best is to learn the theory of Bernoulli polynomials. These are periodic function of period $2\pi$ whose restriction to the interval $[0,2\pi]$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Mathematica gives

$$S=\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-i x}\right)}{2}$$

which isn't really enlightening given what generated it.

Comment: This is just a Fourier series of a well known function. If you go in reverse, it's quite obvious, just compute the fourier coefficients of $ax^2+bx+c$. How to compute the sum without knowing the answer? I'll find the shortest way and post it below if noone else does.

Answer (score 4):

It's the real part of this function:

$$f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx-\epsilon k }}{k^2}$$
where $\epsilon \to 0$. Take two derivatives over $x$, apply expansions you can afford because $\epsilon$ is differentially small, compute the sum, integrate back with appropriate boundary conditions (known values for $x=0$).

$$f''(x)=-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{ikx-\epsilon k }=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{e^{ix-\epsilon}}{e^{ix-\epsilon}-1}$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{e^{ix-\epsilon}(e^{-ix-\epsilon}-1)}{(e^{ix-\epsilon}-1)(e^{-ix-\epsilon}-1)}$$
$$=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{e^{-2\epsilon}-e^{-\epsilon}e^{ix}}{e^{-2\epsilon}-2e^{-\epsilon}\cos x + 1}=\frac{1-e^{ix}}{2(1-\cos x)}$$
$$Re f''(x)=\frac12$$
$$\int \int Re f''(x)dx\,dx=\frac{x^2}{4}+Cx+D$$
We know from Euler's times that $f(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, which sets $D=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. For $x=\pi$ you get another known sum $\sum (-1)^k/k^2=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$ which gives you $C$.

---

Disclaimer: we can't integrate past singularities of the $f''(x)$ sum, which is ill-defined when $x$ is a multiple of $2\pi$. The integrating constants $C$ and $D$ are different on each subdomain, and the ones above hold between $0$ and $2\pi$. The solution is then periodically extended, which is obvious from the properties of $\cos$ function. Notice a sharp peak (derivative discontinuity) at $x=0$. If you use an absolute value $|x|$ in the linear term (because you know it must be an even function), you only extend the validity to $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ interval. Adding extra series terms is misleading - the error between true values and this expression is not polynomial, it's step-function, and it would be quite strange to choose to write periodic steps as a power series.

Comment: Of course the twice differentiated series doesn't converge (the once differentiated series converges if $x$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$), so this argument isn't rigorous. One can make it rigorous by introducing a convergence-generating factor $r^k$ ($r\in [0,1)$) and taking limits, or by framing it in the context of distributions. As a heuristic argument to find the answer, one need not make it rigorous - but the answer still has to be rigorously justified.

Comment: Physicists don't worry about convergence (OP is physicist, and so am I). It works in the sense of summability methods (if you want to be rigorous). All we're doing is extending analytical functions beyond the series convergence (common regularization method).

Comment: Additionally, we are in Fourier territory, where almost nothing converges uniformly - it's all in the square integrable sense. Recall the Gibbs phenomenon.

Comment: The twice differentiated series doesn't converge in $L^2$ either, for that you need a more general framework. Nothing wrong with that, but I thought it should at least be mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I think now it's ok.

Comment: Yes, I think so too.

Answer (score 3):

I had evaluated this exact series a long time ago and just stumbled upon this question and noticed that this method wasn’t given, so here is the way I evaluated it.

Define $$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n x)}{n^2}$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $F(x)$ is $2\pi$-periodic, WLOG, we may confine ourselves to $0<x<2\pi$. By a simple calculation:

\begin{align} F(x) - F(0) &= \int_{0}^{x} \left(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n t)}{n}\right)\, dt \\
&= \Im \int_{0}^{x} \left(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n t}}{n} \right) \, dt \\
&=\Im \int_{0}^{x} \ln(1-e^{i t}) \, dt \\
&= \Im \int_{0}^{x} \ln \left(2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)e^{i(t-\pi)/2}\right) \, dt \\
&=\Im \int_{0}^{x} \left[ \ln \left(2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{i(t-\pi)}{2}\right]\, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t-\pi}{2} \, dt = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}\end{align}

Since $F(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, this implies that $$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n x)}{n^2} = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$$

For self-containment, here is a proof that $F(0)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ via this method:

Notice $\cos(\pi n) = (-1)^{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Recall the trivial property that $$\eta (s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} = (1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$
Take $x \to \pi$:
$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$
$$\implies \zeta (2) (2^{-1}-1) - \zeta(2) = -\frac{\pi^2}{4} \implies -\frac{3}{2} \zeta(2) = -\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$ $$\implies \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ $\square$

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

Compute the coefficients of the Fourier series for an arc of parabola 
$$y(x)=(x-\pi)^2 \:\:\:\:\text{for}\:\:\:\:0<x<2\pi$$
You will identify $\:\:\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}\:\:$ in it and then found :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}=\frac{1}{4}(x-\pi)^2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Yes it's easy if you know the answer :) I believe that was one of the earliest ways to compute Euler's sums. But without knowing how to "guess" the function, you have to do it the hard way :) However, it should be noted that among physicists, fourier transforms of polynomials are recognized immediately - the fact that fourier coefficients at $k^{-n}$ signify $x^n$ behaviour of the signal is burned into the minds of everyone that deals with signal processing. So, good to have this answer on record.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, obviously the sum makes you think to Fourier series. Then, considering the integral definition of the coefficients of any Fourier series, what function leads to the coefficient $\frac{1}{k^2}$ ? This leads to an integral equation which solving gives the answer : the function is a parabola.

Comment: I know, this was my original hint in the comments, so +1 for this answer, it's the most straightforward one. Just, one can't help but wonder how to solve this without the Ansatz. That's why I also posted a different solution.

Comment: @orion : I agree with "the hard way" if one doesn't want to refer to knowledge about Fourier series. So +1 for the hard way.

Comment: What would be $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^2}$ ? Any idea ? Cheers.

Comment: Hi ! it's more arduous : $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^2}=\text{Im}\left(\text{Li}_2 (e^{i\;x}) \right)$$ $\text{Li}_n(x)$ is the polylogarithm function. $\text{Im}(.)$ is the imaginary part (real function).

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a very rigorous answer at all.*

Let us consider $$I=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}\qquad ,\qquad J =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(kx)}{k^2}$$ $$I+iJ=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(e^{ix})^k}{k^2}=\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function.

So, $$I=\Re\left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{+i x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-i
   x}\right)\right)$$ $$J=\Im\left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(e^{+i
   x}\right)\right)$$

Since, at this point, being stuck, I used brute force generating a table of $201$ equally spaced values $(0\leq x \leq 2 \pi)$ and performed a quadratic regression which led to $$I=0.25 x^2-1.5708 x+1.64493$$ for a residual sum of squares equal to $1.11\times 10^{-27}$ which means a perfect fit.

The second coefficient is obviously $\frac \pi 2$; concerning the third, if $x=0$ or $x=2\pi$, $I=\frac{\pi^2} 6$. So $$I=\frac 14 x^2-\frac \pi 2 x+\frac{\pi^2} 6$$ which is the formula from the handbook.

I hope and wish that you will get some more founded answers (as you are, I am a physicist and not an real mathematician).

Comment: This identity can be seemingly shown rigorously using the identity between $\mathrm{Li}_2$ and Bernoulli polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm $\mathrm{Li}_n(e^{2\pi i x})+(-1)^n \mathrm{Li}_n(e^{-2\pi i x})=-(2\pi i)^n B_n(x)/n!$, so $I=\pi^2 B_2(x/(2\pi))$.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo. Please make an answer. As I said, I was stuck and then use brute force. Thanks.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo that's great, thanks. I can rest assured now.