# Series of almost-alternating reciprocals of squares is non-zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0<a<b<2$ be fixed, and consider the series
\begin{equation}
S:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\big(\cos(k\pi a)-\cos(k\pi b)\big)}{k^2}.
\end{equation}
This series can readily be seen to be convergent.
But for which values of $a$ and $b$, can we ensure that $S\neq 0$?

Comment: It's clear that $S=0$ when $a=b$ or when $a+b=2$. Note that $S = \mathop{\rm Re}\bigl( \mathop{\rm Li}_2(e^{ia\pi})-\mathop{\rm Li}_2(e^{ib\pi}) \bigr)$ where Li${}_2$ is the polylogarithm function; numerical calculations of $S$ using this identity indicate that $\mathop{\rm Re}\bigl( \mathop{\rm Li}_2(e^{ia\pi}) \bigr)$ is decreasing for $0<a<1$ (and symmetric about $a=1$), which would imply that $S\ne0$ except for the special cases already observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(k\pi x)}{k^2}$$
Then $$S=f(a)-f(b)$$
Thus your question is equivalent to determining the domains on which $f$ is injective.

First, $f$ is $2$-periodic, so if $b-a=2 n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, then $f(a)=f(b)$.

Therefore, let's focus on $[0, 2)$.

Using the definition of the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$\text{Li}_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^k}{k^n}$$
you can check that $$f(x)=\frac{\text{Li}_2(e^{i\pi x})+\text{Li}_2(e^{-i\pi x})}{2}$$
Then $$\begin{split}
f^\prime(x)&=i\pi\frac{e^{i\pi x}\,\text{Li}^\prime_2(e^{i\pi x})-e^{-i\pi x}\,\text{Li}^\prime_2(e^{-i\pi x})}{2}\\
&=\frac{i\pi}{2}\left(\text{Li}_1(e^{i\pi x})-\text{Li}_1(e^{-i\pi x}) \right)\\
&=\frac{i\pi}2 \left(-\ln(1-e^{i\pi x}) + \ln(1-e^{-i\pi x}) \right)\\
&=\frac{i\pi}2\ln\left(-e^{-i\pi x}\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{2}(x-1)
\end{split}$$
Thus $f$ decreases on $[0, 1)$ and increases on $[1, 2)$.

You can also directly integrate the derivative, to get $$f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}2\left(\frac {x^2} 2-x\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}(x-1)^2-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
Here's a plot of the function
[image: plot of f]
As noted by @Greg Martin, the function is symmetric around $x=1$ (parabola). At this point you should have all the information you need to answer your question.

Comment: $\pi^2/4(x-1)^2 -\pi^2/12$ makes the symmetry about $x = 1$ more obvious.

Comment: Good point. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Use this [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626131/how-to-do-sum-k-1-infty-frac-coskxk2/4444724#4444724):

> \begin{align} F(x) - F(0) &= \int_{0}^{x} \left(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n t)}{n}\right)\, dt \\
> &= \Im \int_{0}^{x} \left(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i n t}}{n} \right) \, dt \\
> &=\Im \int_{0}^{x} \ln(1-e^{i t}) \, dt \\
> &= \Im \int_{0}^{x} \ln \left(2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)e^{i(t-\pi)/2}\right) \, dt \\
> &=\Im \int_{0}^{x} \left[ \ln \left(2\sin\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\right)+\frac{i(t-\pi)}{2}\right]\, dt \\
> &= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t-\pi}{2} \, dt = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}\end{align}
> Since $F(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, this implies that $$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (n x)}{n^2} = \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$$

Now, let $x=a\pi$ and $x=b\pi$

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (k\pi a)}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (k\pi b)}{k^2}\\
\\
S&= \left(\frac{a^2\pi^2}{4}-\frac{a\pi^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)-\left(\frac{b^2\pi^2}{4}-\frac{b\pi^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)\\
\\
S&=0~~\Longleftrightarrow ~~a=b ~~~\text{or}~~~ a+b=2 
\end{align}$$

So as long as $a\neq b$ and $a+b\neq 2$, then $S\neq 0$