Explicit form of $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(mk)}{m^2}$ for $k \in [-\pi,\pi]$
Explicit form of $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(mk)}{m^2}$ for $k \in [-\pi,\pi]$?

I know for $k \in [0,2\pi]$ then the simplifies to $\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi}{2}k - \frac{k^2}{4}$ by Gradshteyn's book. For negative $k$, only the linear term changes sign. Does that mean the linear term vanishes for $k \in [-\pi,\pi]$?

It should be $+\frac {k^2}4$ (see this thread ). This is a Fourier series of period $2 \pi$ so that the (partial) parabola over $[0,2\pi]$ will be repeated over $\mathbb{R}$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function .

Since$^{(*)}$
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(mk)}{m^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi}{2}k + \frac{k^2}{4} \tag{1}
$$
for $k\in[0,2\pi]$, and the LHS of $(1)$ is an even function of $k$, it must be equal to the even extension of the RHS of $(1)$ in the interval $[-2\pi,0]$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(mk)}{m^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi}{2}|k| + \frac{k^2}{4} \tag{2}
$$
for $k\in[-2\pi,2\pi]$ --- in particular, for $k\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

$^{(*)}$ See, for instance, How to do $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kx)}{k^2}$? and Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}$.

Ah, that is very simple. Thank you.
If you don't mind, in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4444724/597047 i wanted to understand two things: where they use the fact that $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$ and how the third line of the $F(x)-F(0)$ work is obtained from the second. That is, where does that natural log come from?

I suggest that you ask those questions to the author of that answer.

If you are interested in using complex integration, the solution to a more general sum can be found (the solutions in the links do not use such approach).
Let's consider
$$S(a)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(km)}{m^2+a^2}=\frac12\sum_{m=-\infty;\,m\neq0}^\infty\frac{e^{ikm}}{m^2+a^2}$$
and the function
$$f(z)=\frac{2\pi i}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac{e^{ikz}}{z^2+a^2},\quad k\in[0;2\pi]$$
We integrate this function along a big circle $C_R$ in the complex plane (radius $R\to\infty$). We choose the radius in such a way to avoid "dangerous" points $z=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$, choosing, for example $R_n=n+\frac12;\, n=1,2,3, ...\to\infty$.
Then
$$\oint_{C_R}f(z)dz=2\pi i\left(\underset{z=\pm1;\pm2;...}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}+\underset{z=0}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}+\underset{z=\pm ia}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}\right)$$
For $z$ on this big circle and $k\in[0;2\pi]\,\,\big|\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}\big|<\big|\frac{const}{z^2+a^2}\big|$
As $\oint_{C_R}\frac{dz}{z^2+a^2}\to 0$ at $R_n\to\infty$, and using
$$\underset{z=\pm1;\pm2;...}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}=2S(a)$$
we get
$$\oint_{C_R}f(z)dz\to0=2S(a)+\underset{z=0}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}+\underset{z=\pm ia}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{2\pi i\,e^{ikz}}{e^{2\pi iz}-1}\frac1{z^2+a^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 2S(a)=\frac\pi a\left(\frac{e^{ka}}{e^{2\pi a}-1}-\frac{e^{-ka}}{e^{-2\pi a}-1}\right)-\frac1{a^2}$$
$$\boxed{\,\,S(a)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(km)}{m^2+a^2}=\frac\pi {2a}\frac{\cosh a(k-\pi)}{\sinh \pi a}-\frac1{2a^2}\,\,}$$
Leading $a\to0$
$$S=S(0)=\frac{(k-\pi)^2}4-\frac{\pi^2}{12}=\frac{k^2}4-\frac{\pi k}2+\frac{\pi^2}6;\quad k\in[0;2\pi]$$
If we want to consider $k$ on the interval $[-2\pi;2\pi]$, the answer is
$$S=\frac{k^2}4-\frac{\pi |k|}2+\frac{\pi^2}6;\quad k\in[-2\pi;2\pi]$$
as @Gonçalo explained in his post.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{mk} \over m^{2}}
\right\vert_{k\ \in\ \bracks{-\pi,\pi}}} =
\Re\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{\expo{\ic\verts{k}}}^{m} \over m^{2}} \sr{\rm by\ def.}{=}
\Re\on{Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{\ic\verts{k}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\Re\on{Li}_{\color{red}{2}}\pars{\rule{0pt}{5mm}\expo{2\pi\ic\bracks{\color{red}{\verts{k}/2\pi}}}\,} =
{1 \over 2}\bracks{-\,{\pars{2\pi\ic}^{\color{red}{2}} \over \color{red}{2}!}\on{B}_{\color{red}{2}}\pars{\color{red}{\verts{k} \over 2\pi}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
The last expression is Jonqui$\grave{\rm e}$re's Inversion Formula and $\ds{\on{B}_{n}}$ is the
$n$-order Bernoulli Polynomial.
Note that $\ds{\on{B}_{2}\pars{x} = x^{2} - x + 1/6}$ which reduces \eqref{1} to
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}
{\cos\pars{mk} \over m^{2}}
\right\vert_{k\ \in\ \bracks{-\pi,\pi}}} =
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 4}k^{2} - {\pi \over 2}\verts{k} + {\pi^{2} \over 6}}} \\ &
\end{align}
